# Accessing Google Contacts via App Engine and Android App

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, google-contacts-api

I have a android app and a connected web app in PHP (I will move it to App Engine in few days).

1. I want to manage users' contacts via Web as well as the android app. Is there any good blog or a language library that can help with managing contacts via App Engine? The [Google Contacts API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) seems too confusing and vague. Also, I have bit experience  in App Engine.
2. In this scenario, is it possible that if the user has granted access permission only on the android app, the App Engine server can manage the contacts in background (via exchanging Tokens possibly)?

*PS. Spare me for my english and this long question.*

Comment: You'll most likely use Google API client library to do that on GAE: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/.